# Anyone know of an online notebook app which syncs or works with Symbian?

Tags: webapp-rec

Evernote has a buggy beta, but then they stopped development on it citing a few issues. Right now there's nothing that can sync. Maybe I need to switch from ol' Symbian.

Comment: you can surf to evernote.com (the webapp) with your mobile as well ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try [Upvise Notebooks](http://www.upvise.com/business/notebooks.aspx)

Comment: They don't specifically have a symbian application. Its a general Java app. Pretty restrictive when it gets to symbian. But then I guess I'll close this question off.

Comment: Link only answer.